# Easier said than done vs. Easier to say than do

Tags: etymology, idioms, passive-voice

As a speaker of English as a second language, I've long been curious to know why English speakers would choose to say "Easier said than done" over "Easier to say than do".

Why should it be said in the passive voice, not in the active one?

Or is it simply a matter of being idiomatic?

Comment: Both are fine. It's just how the idiom worked out. "Easier said than done" also rolls off the tongue quite nicely.

Comment: I think it's just an idiom without much reason behind it. But you could say that the version with past participles emphasises completion of the actions, while using the to-infinitive could refer to starting the actions, and some things are easy to start but not to finish.